# Openshift Origin rhc setup on localhost fails

Tags: openshift-client-tools, openshift-origin, openshift-cartridge

I am trying to setup a new openshift origin environment locally on a virtualbox deployment.  The tutorial that I followed for this operation is found [here](https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-3-on-your-local-environment/) and it worked fine.  I am now trying to install the client tools in the virtual environment and then setup my rhc configuration.  I have everything installed and I am running the following command 'rhc setup --debug'.

Below is my output with the error in tow:

```
    [vagrant@origin ~]$ rhc setup --debug
    DEBUG: Using config file /home/vagrant/.openshift/express.conf
    DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
    OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

    This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your 
    application namespace, and check that other programs like
    Git are properly installed.
    DEBUG: Running server_stage

    If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now.
    Just hit enter to use the server for OpenShift
    Online: openshift.redhat.com.
    Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com| localhost:8443

    You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
    DEBUG: Running login_stage
    DEBUG: Connecting to https://localhost:8443/broker/rest/api
    DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
    DEBUG: Created new httpclient
    DEBUG: Request GET https://localhost:8443/broker/rest/api
    DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
    DEBUG: Certificate validation failed: self signed certificate

    The server's certificate is self-signed, which means that a 
    secure connection can't be established to
    'localhost:8443'.

    You may bypass this check, but any data you send to the server 
    could be intercepted by others.

    Connect without checking the certificate? (yes|no): yes
    DEBUG: Connecting to https://localhost:8443/broker/rest/api
    DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
    DEBUG: Created new httpclient
    DEBUG: Request GET https://localhost:8443/broker/rest/api
    DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
    DEBUG:    code 403   28 ms
    You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

I have also tried passing a username with -l admin and password with -p admin, but I receive the same error.

What do I need to do differently to make this work properly?  Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution to this? (other than replacing the self-signed cert)